# How to get the value base on range of two number in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Result of my code is `0` I want to return the value base on what
there `basic_salary` belongs for eg. His `basic_salary` is `40,000` it
returns the value of  `"ee": 400`

```
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm" >
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Contribution</th>                            
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                       <tr v-for="(fetch, count) in SalaryData">            
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" v-bind:value="deducted = contribution(fetch.basic_salary)">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
```

In my methods....

```
contribution(value){   
  return Object.values(this.contriDatas).reduce((acc, val)=>{    
    if(value >= val.range_from && value <= val.range_to) 
    return val.ee
    else return 0
         
  },0)
    
},
```

this is the data structure of `contriDatas`

```
 [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "range_from": 1000,
        "range_to": 1249.99,
        "er": 83.7,
        "ee": 36.3,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "range_from": 1250,
        "range_to": 1749.99,
        "er": 120.5,
        "ee": 54.5,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "range_from": 3500,
        "range_to": 3600,
        "er": 300,
        "ee": 300,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "range_from": 4000,
        "range_to": 4500,
        "er": 400,
        "ee": 400,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      }
    ]
```

Data structure of `SalaryData`

```
[
  {     
    "basic_salary": 1300,   
  },
  {
    "basic_salary": 50000,   
  }
]
```

Comment: Anyone can help me to solve this? All help is Appreciated

Comment: `return vale.ee` should be `return value.ee` no?

Comment: I updated my question.. but still not working

Comment: `reduce` runs through the whole array ... so what is returned is the result of the last iteration - it's really odd to use `reduce` yet never use the value of `acc` ... I think you may be using the wrong tool - do you expect more than one `val` to meet the conditions?

Comment: @Bravo what can I use ..  the value of val repeat it 2x? pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is for when you to flatten an array of elements into a single value. But what you want to do is [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the first element in the array that matches the condition `value >= val.range_from && value <= val.range_to`, and return its `ee` field.

It may look something like this:

```js
contribution(value){   
  const data = this.contriDatas.find(x => value >= x.range_from && value <= x.range_to)
  if (data) {
    return data.ee
  }
  return 0
},
```

find returns `undefined` if no element matches, so there is a conditional that checks if data is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). If an element is found, its `ee` value is returned, otherwise this returns `0`.

Comment: It only read the first index of `basic_salary` I have two data` [
  {     
    "basic_salary": 1300,   
  },
  {
    "basic_salary": 50000,   
  }
]`

Comment: You are not showing any code that actually deals with `basic_salary` - so how can we fix that code for you as well?

Comment: Oh, is it showing `0` for the second? that'll be because 50000 does not fall into any range

Comment: exactly ... the only valid ranges you have are 1000-1250, 1250-1750, and 3500-3600 ... anything not falling into one of those ranges will result in 0 ... 40000 -> 4500 is not a proper range, since 4500 is LESS than 40000

Comment: @NotaPro The reason `40000` doesn't return `400` is because the `range_to` field is smaller than the `range_from` field. Should `4500` be `45000`?

Comment: @bravo OH SORRY HAHA I thought It was `4000` I It wokrs !!

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts sorrry haha What I see is `4000` but its `40000` sorry

Answer (score 1):

Reduce iterates the whole array - so you're getting the result of the last iteration

You want to find the correct object, and return the `ee` property ...

So use array find - like so

```
return Object.values(this.contriDatas)
.find(data => value >= data.range_from && value <= data.range_to)?.ee || 0;
```

or, or less modern browsers

```
return (Object.values(this.contriDatas)
.find(data => value >= data.range_from && value <= data.range_to) || {ee:0}).ee;
```

test code to show it DOES work

```js
const contriDatas = [{
    "id": 1,
    "range_from": 1000,
    "range_to": 1249.99,
    "er": 83.7,
    "ee": 36.3,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "range_from": 1250,
    "range_to": 1749.99,
    "er": 120.5,
    "ee": 54.5,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "range_from": 3500,
    "range_to": 3600,
    "er": 300,
    "ee": 300,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "range_from": 40000,
    "range_to": 4500,
    "er": 400,
    "ee": 400,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
];
const test = value => {
  return Object.values(contriDatas)
  .find(data => value >= data.range_from && value <= data.range_to)?.ee || 0;
}

console.log(test(3500));
console.log(test(100));
console.log(test(1500));
```

Comment: Oh ... OK, so you're using some browser that is too old for `?.` - sorry, I thought most people used an environment that could handle modern javascript by transpiling it - the other answer does the exact same thing as this, but older browsers will work with that code - though, you seem to have issues with that code - perhaps because your ranges don't include 50000

Comment: Can you do another code that not using `?` not working to me  :(

Comment: I've added alternative to both `?.` and to the other answer - because there's always many ways to do the same thing in javascript